# Why are there open ports on my home network router?

Tags: network, nmap, router, ports

It can be a security risk to have unwarranted [open ports](https://superuser.com/questions/82488/why-is-it-bad-to-have-open-ports).

So I ran `nmap 192.168.0.1` to investigate if I had open ports on my home network, it turns out, I do:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
5431/tcp  open  park-agent
49163/tcp open  unknown
```

This concerned me. However, [upon further reading](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/router-ports-open), I have discovered that running `nmap` from my home desktop does not obtain the actual open ports, but rather ports which are accessible from my desktop on *the local  network side*; I'm interested in ports open to the Internet at large.

Therefore, I tethered my desktop to my phone Wi-Fi Hotspot and ran `nmap` again, this time I am outside of my local network, i.e. I am not connected to my home router provided by my ISP but rather connected to the Internet through my phone service provider. I ran `nmap` again, this time using the external `IP Address` of my home network. The output is as follows:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
80/tcp   open   http
113/tcp  closed ident
443/tcp  open   https
1935/tcp open   rtmp
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
```

There are still numerous open ports, which I was not expecting, as I am not running any servers and simply use my home network for Internet browsing.

Given the answers [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/router-ports-open), I do not think I should have any open ports.

Why are these ports open to begin with? And should I be concerned/close them?

**Edit**: I have a single gateway device provided to me by my ISP. I have one desktop connected to this device. My ISP is Sky.

Comment: those are not likely to be the open ports on your router, but ports made accessible by your ISP to their own resources - simple test: browse to your IP and connect to FTP

Comment: That is correct, these ports are ports that ISPs usually intercept to either protect the average user from accidentally opening these ports and getting hacked, and/or because their terms of service don't allow running FTP and HTTPD servers. Try to access those services and see what you get.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle thank you. Still, why is my ISP advertising these ports as open to the outside world, does it not make more sense that these ports are filtered?

Comment: @schroeder thank you. If I run `ftp nn.nnn.nnn.nnn` from the command line, from outside of my LAN, it shows as "Connected to nn.nnn.nnn.nnn.". Does this mean that anyone, who knew my external IP Address, could create a connection in this manner? For what purpose would my ISP want this configuration, does it not create a security flaw?

Comment: @case_2501 you are assuming that you are connecting to your router. Have you logged into your router to see if there is any FTP service? What happens when you run `ls` on the ftp connection?

Comment: @schroeder I've logged into my router, by typing my IP into my browser and entering my admin name and password. I've navigated to "security>firewall rules>Inbound Services", the "action" here is "BLOCK always". Therefore, I would conclude there is no FTP service. I subsequently added the inbound service `FTP(TCP:20,21)`. I then ran `FTP` again from the command line, and `ls` as suggested. The output is: "421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection".

Comment: @schroeder thank you for being so helpful, I'd up-vote but I have no reputation. Ultimately, I think I am missing a conceptual model in my mind of how everything fits together, I am clearly missing certain layers. I keep reading Wiki pages on TCP/IP model etc. but I cannot seem to translate the model into the real world. I really need to start studying networks from the ground up, but really do not know where to start.

Comment: The fact that you connect does not necessarily mean the connection is to your router. If your ISP is intercepting, then you are connected to them on that port, not you. You should be able to ascertain what you are connected to by the ftp login message, or the page returned on http. If that is not giving you clues, then power your router off and connect. If still you can connect, it isn't your device that the connection is ported through to.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle thank you. There does not appear to be a ftp login message, `ftp nn.nnn.nnn.nnn` simply returns `Connected to nn.nnn.nnn.nnn.", it does not ask for credentials. The page returned on http is completely blank. If I enter http://nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:21 it searches indefinitely. How this all fits together is not making sense to me, although I appreciate I am not connecting to my 'router', rather to the ISP's hardware, so thank you for taking the time to show me that.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle I also powered off my home router, and got exactly the same results when running `nmap` and `ftp nn.nnn.nnn.nnn.`. So I can see now that these open ports are not directly related to my home router. This raises more questions for me than it answers however. How does my ISP forward packets to me? Using the same IP address? But that IP address is not actually my address. Perhaps it's more to do with the MAC address of my home router. Does my ISP translate addresses. Why does my ISP advertise these ports as open on its systems. I clearly have a lot of work to do. Thanks again.

Comment: It is simple firewall technology. Everything that is destined for your home is examined and the traffic destined to those ports are sent elsewhere. They are employing network address translation (NAT) to conceal the actual address where that is re-directed to make it appear with your ip.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle I'm beginning to understand, I think. So, when I search the Internet for "my ip address", the address returned by the website is not actually _my_ IP Address at all, but actually one of a range of IP Addresses assigned to my local ISP, who in turn maps this IP address to me, using NAT? Does this IP Address stay the same, or is the address my ISP uses to find my router different?

Comment: Yes, that is their IP which they assign to you, and they direct all traffic to that address to you, except those ports they direct elsewhere and handle. Your router handles making all the devices on your home network appear as a single ip address to the external world, with that one address being the one the ISP has assigned. That is network address translation.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle One final thing I cannot comprehend, is how does my home router talk to my ISP. If my external IP Address is 1.2.3.4, and packets routed to this address get sent to my ISP, how does my ISP forward these packets on to me? Is there another IP Address assigned to my home router that we do not see. Or is the external IP Address 1.2.3.4 used internally on the ISP’s network as well? In other words, does address translation happen twice, once on my home router and then again when it reaches the ISP? I think not, but it could, and I wouldn’t know?

Comment: NAT is done on your router for the traffic between you and the Internet. Your router is assigned the IP your ISP has assigned. When a device on your internal net makes an outbound connection, your router kind of proxies that and establishes the connection. As far as the outside world knows, the session is between your router and the external service. But when your router receives packets from that session, it sends them to your internal device. Usually, the only natting is on your router, to conceal your internal net.

Comment: But when your ISP intercepts and redirects traffic to these ports, that gets natted by them, but kind of in reverse. Traffic to those ports gets port forwarded to their servers, and as part of port forwarding there is also natting such that the end result is what you have experienced. Most ISPs just filter those ports, so that connections just fail. If they had done that, it would have been better for you because you wouldn't have been alarmed.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle thank you for taking the time to answer my queries. Again, if you would like to submit an answer I will accept it. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should close them if you have such capability and have no reason to allow incoming connections.

What you did not state, however, is what your home network looks like. Do you have a cable modem and external router, or single gateway device? or?  Who is your ISP?
 Depending on your ISP, you might be talking to an IP entity on their network or on your LAN.

Comment: thank you. I have a single gateway device provided to me by my ISP. I have one desktop connected to this device. My ISP is Sky. I've edited my question to include this information. Please could you clarify your last sentence for me, as I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: @case_2501 the last line is what I commented on under your question - the ports might not go to your device but to something in the ISP's network - you can test this

Comment: @schroeder thank you. My knowledge of networking is in its infancy to say the least. If I'm querying my external IP Address with Nmap, and the IP Address is associated with my gateway device, why is Nmap talking to a ISP resource not specified in the command?

Comment: @case_2501 look up "port forwarding" - it's normal for ISPs to redirect traffic, like port 80, so that someone does not try to host their own websites from home, for instance - to help you think through the networking, think of it this way: your external IP is not directly tied to your device, it gets to your device eventually, but it passes through a lot of ISP layers first

Comment: @schroeder thank you. I'll do some further reading. I'm flicking through articles left, right and center on the Internet, and I'm finding it difficult to get a coherent picture, can you recommend a specific resource that would really give me a thorough and detailed understanding; i'm hesitant to go off Amazon book reviews, and Wikipedia/Internet articles seem to repeat the same, quite superficial, information. Any guidance you can give to help me help myself would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @case_2501 "_If I'm querying my external IP Address with Nmap, and the IP Address is associated with my gateway device_". I'm not an InfoSec expert, but I believe the IP address you're using is only "_sort of_" the IP address of the box-in-the-corner of your room... in reality, any attempt to access that IP passes through your ISP's hardware/software and they may be intercepting certain ports and consuming them themselves (with the rest passed to your box-in-the-corner).

Answer (score -1):

You are right it's a security issue, and there are already documented cases of massive hacks done thru home routers, for example in Brasil:

https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/

Most routers will let you do DMZ, port-forwarding, etc. However such ports should be disabled/closed/firewalled by default.

The very least what your ISP should have done is ensured that ports like the ones you have enlisted are accessible (open) only from their corporate IP's if they are using it to collect some usage data, etc...

They could have done it at their core firewalls/routers... My suggestion is to report security issue to your ISP, and monitor if they have corrected it, if not, then seek for another ISP, but ask them for mentioned security issue.

Or try to put flash your router with software like DD-WRT.

Comment: Why would the ISP be responsible for that? I would hate my ISP even more if they decided to block my ports.

Comment: Those are the ports from your modem/router... And you can configure port-forwarding, DMZ etc... But you should rather check what's running on them...

Comment: Of course you should check what's running on them, but why would you want your ISP to block them?

Comment: I mean ports for router's config, they should be accessible from your lan and from their corporate IP's not from the rest of the world...